# Arithmetic overflow error when converting float to datetime (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a column that has dates as float data type. They are in a YYYYMMDD format. I need to change these dates back into a datetime format.

I tried doing the following:

```
Select top 1 Date_col,CAST(FLOOR((CAST(Date_col AS numeric(10,10)))) AS DATETIME)  from dbo.table_2016
```

All I need is to convert the data type, but I would like to retain the formatting if possible.

Comment: Try using Convert instead.      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: `CAST(FLOOR(date_col) AS DATETIME)`?

Comment: That was the answer on a similar question on SO. Thought I would try it. Already tried a regular "Cast" but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    DATEFROMPARTS(  
        left(convert(char(8), convert(integer, Date_Col)), 4),
        substring(convert(char(8), convert(integer, Date_Col)), 5, 2),
        substring(convert(char(8), convert(integer, Date_Col)), 7, 2))
from
    table_2016;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After running your code I realized that there is one row in my table that has a date of 0 for some reason. This was what was likely throwing up the error. Your code helped me realize that

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @Adit2789 - I think what the problem was that got fixed here, is that a date switches to float based on the number of days since the start of 1900, with the part after the decimal point representing time - your format is more like a date string changed into a number - it is actually about the year 55000 - beyond SQLs 9999 limit -